# How do I use { text } in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon

I am trying to use Storybooks `import { text } from '@storybook/addon-knobs', to allow my users to enter there own text in a particular story.

I've tried going through the docs, and actually they aren't very helpful. Would someone be able to show me a basic example of a Storybook Story that uses `text` so users can input their own text please?

I am using React 16 by the way

I also tried using Storybook Docs and used the following example...

```
import React from 'react';
import { text } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

// Knobs as dynamic variables.
export const asDynamicVariables = () => {
  const name = text('Name', 'James');
  const content = `I am ${name}.`;

  return <div>{content}</div>;
};
```

But didn't get what I was expecting, which was an area where users could input there own text...

I'm also adding to my pain by trying to do this in MDX format :/

Comment: What documentation did you read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@storybook/addon-knobs` is now deprecated in favor of `@storybook/addon-controls`.

[Documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls) for using controls. Example with MDX:

```js
<!-- Button.stories.mdx -->

import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/addon-docs';

import { Button } from './Button';

<Meta title="Button" component={Button} />

export const Template = (args) => ({
   // Your template goes here
});

<Story 
  name="Primary"
  args={{ 
    variant: 'primary',
  }}>
  {Template.bind({})}
</Story>
```

Check the complete control types list [here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls#annotation).
You'd be using the same `text` option as in your code

[image]